# AWS Glue: Command failed with error code 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I've been battling this error for weeks now.  I have tried many different applications and cannot find any consistency with this error.  Sometimes, if I change the job bookmarking setting it paused, enabled, or back to disabled it starts working.  I have a java jar that I am referencing to the glue job and I am calling a few methods from it.  Sometimes if I rebuild the artifact the job starts working and no longer throws this error.  I have another job that uses the same exact jar and doesn't throw the error ever.  I have tried creating a new job to start over, but I am seeing the same issue.  Here is there error stack that it gives in the logs.  The code from the application is a simple dataframe read from S3 and write to another location in s3.

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(source)

df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save(destination)
```

The error stack:

```
18/04/30 14:40:35 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlue.getJobBookmark(Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkResult;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlue.getJobBookmark(Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkResult;
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JobBookmarkServiceShim$$anonfun$2.apply(JobBookmarkUtils.scala:54)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JobBookmarkServiceShim$$anonfun$2.apply(JobBookmarkUtils.scala:54)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JobBookmarkServiceShim.<init>(JobBookmarkUtils.scala:54)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JobBookmark$.configure(JobBookmarkUtils.scala:178)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job$.init(Job.scala:68)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job$.init(Job.scala:32)
at NetezzaRawToRefined$.main(script_2018-04-30-14-39-54.scala:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueExceptionWrapper$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(GlueExceptionWrapper.scala:29)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueExceptionWrapper$$anonfun$1.apply(GlueExceptionWrapper.scala:29)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueExceptionWrapper$$anonfun$1.apply(GlueExceptionWrapper.scala:29)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueExceptionWrapper$.delayedEndpoint$com$amazonaws$services$glue$util$GlueExceptionWrapper$1(GlueExceptionWrapper.scala:28)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueExceptionWrapper$delayedInit$body.apply(GlueExceptionWrapper.scala:11)
at scala.Function0$
class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueExceptionWrapper$.main(GlueExceptionWrapper.scala:11)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueExceptionWrapper.main(GlueExceptionWrapper.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
18/04/30 14:40:35 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlue.getJobBookmark(Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkResult;)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlue.getJobBookmark(Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobBookmarkResult;
```

This error typically happens if your run time has different version of jar than your packaged version. I would suggest to make sure you are packing same version of jar.

Comment: So, my research brought that up as well.  However, I have two glue jobs using the same jar, so the version is the same for both.  One of the jobs works, and the other one doesn't.  We don't have the option of changing the version either.

I do wonder if you end up with a different aws java sdk version based on when you create the job itself.  I will test and find out.  Thanks.

Comment: You're right, it was due to an aws-java-sdk jar getting included.  The versions would end up being different when running in glue.

Comment: where do you put this ? in the script ? or glue job ?